# Golf MK3 battery drains, rapid clicking on start, glow plug light flashes

Tags: vw, ignition, diesel, golf, glowplugs

**Does anybody know what would cause the following symptoms?**

I have a **1996 Golf MK3 diesel (not TDI).**

I drove the car with no problem three days ago. Today I went to start it, and **the battery is almost dead.**

When I turn the ignition key, there is a **rapid clicking noise** and the **glow plug indicator flashes rapidly.** The motor won't turn over.

*That was today. Everything below was two weeks ago:*

One day the car worked fine and **the next day the oil pressure lamp and battery indicator flickered red.**

I started out on my trip and **the battery was drained in less than an hour,** but when I jumpstarted the car it ran fine.

I made an appointment with the garage, jumpstarted the car and started driving there.

En route, the same symptoms persisted, but then **there was a noisy CLICK and everything seemed to go back to normal.**

The mechanic **replaced the alternator** and told me the problem was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the story about your car, but do you have a question? Did you charge/replace the battery? Did you call back your mechanic?

Comment: My question is: what is going on (I edited the text to ask it more directly). I will call back the mechanic tomorrow, but I thought it would be good to have an idea of likely causes before talking to him. Two mechanics have tested the battery and found it to be good. I am leaning towards the idea that the problem is a bad connection between the battery and the rest.

Comment: Your problem could possibly be explained by corrosion at either end of either battery cable, or even corrosion inside the wire insulation itself.

Comment: Thanks. That corresponds to other information I have read online. I'll ask the mechanic about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was that t**he battery was bad**. Apparently it was a cheap battery and **the failed alternator drained it**.

Once it had been drained, it would no longer hold a charge.

Replacing the batter with a new, good-quality (VW) battery fixed the problem entirely.

One clue was that when I jumpstarted the car, **all the symptoms went away** -- no blinking lights etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your mechanic seems to have repaired the fault by replacing the alternator. A faulty alternator will drain the battery as you describe and can be quite dramatic in causing other symptoms.